# How to use 'even so'?

Tags: adverbs

*We were staying at the most expensive hotel in town. But, even so, there were no toilet rolls in the washroom.*

I was struck by the use of 'even so' in the above sentence. Is it correct? Shouldn't it be more like: *The hotel room didn't have much amenities, but, even so, it had the best view in town.*

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think the use of *even so* in the first sentence is incorrect? It means ‘in spite of this fact’. It’s because the hotel was the most expensive in town that the writer expected the washroom to be appropriately provisioned.

In your second sentence, incidentally, it would be normal to write *many amenities* rather than *much amenities*.

Comment: Barrie, I thought it is a bit off because the dictionary defines 'even so' as 'despite anything to the contrary (followed by a concession)'. E.g. There's a lot of evil in the world, but even so. there is Barrie helping out on stackexchange.

What I mean is that I always thought that 'but also' was used with a hint of relief in the tone, and not just as a replacement for 'although', 'nonetheless'...

Comment: @user52023: So you're suggesting that "A even so B" should only be used if A is a bad thing and B is a good thing?

Answer (score 0):

Your two examples are identical in the usage of even so.

I felt sick, but even so, I still went to work

I was laughing, but even so, I felt sad

There may be no need for the comma after the but.

Comment: It's "more correct" with the comma after "but", as the phrase is "even so", not "but even so". "Even so" should be parenthetical to the "but". Comma use is becoming more relaxed, so it may be acceptable without this comma (check your preferred style guide), but pedants would prefer to see it used there.

Comment: Updated. However the dictionaries I saw have no comma after the but

Comment: This is a delayed reply, but, even so: I would be interested to know what dictionaries. Do you have sources/links? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

'Even so' is alright, but one of the great things about English is that there is an immense vocabulary from which to select. It is not a good thing to use the same expression twice on the same page, or too often, as it points to lack of literacy. As well as 'even so' you can use, 'nonetheless', 'however', 'though' etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's not used in this way very often any more, but even used roughly equivalent to exactly: "Hath she died in childbed? Even so."

Comment: This does not relate to the usage in the question.